# what is CPU LOAD AVERAGE?

Tags: nginx, server, webmin, cpu-load

Ok I am new in this, and I don't know how to handle CPU Load Average. I want to know more about it. What type of problems I will get if I don't prepare for it? What I must have to know about CPU Load Average?

At my website CPU LOAD Average is 0.30 to 0.31, but today it suddenly increases to 0.61 to 0.62... I know that its something important, please help me to know about it.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see there is no CPU load on your server, If you are facing server load issues then I will suggest you please monitor your server through **top** and **ps -aufx** command. With this command you can find out exact root cause of your server load issues.